# Swagger not using "host" in v2.23.0

Tags: apache-camel

We just upgraded from v.2.21.x to v2.23.0 
We are setting "host" in our RestConfiguration

That used to show up correctly in v.2.21 in the /api-docs endpoint 
Now, the host shown there is whatever is coming in on the Request to 
/api-docs

I'm not sure where to look. Is RestSwaggerServlet still used, under the 
covers? If not, what's a good place to look in the code, to see what Camel 
is doing when we hit  /api-docs

Answer (score 0):

This should now be fixed, in Camel v2.24 onward. See this [JIRA ticket CAMEL-13126](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13126).

It will require setting the useXForwardHeaders option in RestConfiguration. See [documentation here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/0dc62ead04726f9a2eb12245f904736bd913485f/docs/user-manual/modules/ROOT/pages/rest-dsl.adoc).

Basically, if you want to ignore the incoming X-Forward-Headers and use the exact value that you are setting in "host", then set this config parameter to **false**.